# Python Couchbase pipeline() kills interpreter with large batches

Tags: python, performance, batch-processing, couchbase, throughput

So I wanted to use the python driver to batch insert documents to Couchbase. However if the batch exceeds few thousand documents the python kernel gets restarted (I'm using notebook).

To reproduce this please try:

```
from couchbase.bucket import Bucket
cb = Bucket('couchbase://localhost/default')
keys_per_doc = 50
doc_count = 10000
docs = [dict(
    [
        ('very_long_feature_{}'.format(i), float(i) if i % 2 == 0 else i)
        for i in xrange(keys_per_doc)
    ] + [('id', id_)] ) for id_ in xrange(doc_count)]

def sframe_to_cb(sf, key_column, key_prefix):
    pipe = cb.pipeline()
    with pipe:
        for r in sf:
            cb.upsert(key_prefix + str(r[key_column]), r)
    return 0
p = sframe_to_cb(docs, 'id', 'test_')
```

The fun thing is that all docs get inserted and I suppose the interpreter dies when gathering the results on the pipeline.**exit** method.

I don't get any error message and the notebook console just says that it has restarted the notebook.

I'm curious what is causing this behavior and if there is a way to fix it.

Obviously I can do mini-batches (up to 3000 docs in my case) but this makes it much slower if they are processed sequentially.

I cannot use multiprocessing because I run the inserts inside of celery.

I cannot use multiple celery tasks because the serialisation of batches is too expensive and could kill our redis instance.

So the questions:

What is causing the crash with large batches and is there a way to fix it?
Assuming that nothing can go wrong with upserts can I make the pipeline discard results.
Is there a different way to achieve high throughput from a single process?

Aditional info as requested in comments:

- VMWarte fusion on Mac running a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM
- The guest ubuntu has 4GB RAM, 12GB swap on SSD, 2 cores (4 threads)
- The impression that doing mini batches is slower comes from watching the bucket statsistics (large batch peaks at 10K TPS smaller ones get c.a. 2K TPS)
- There is a large speed up if I use multiprocessing and these batches are distributed across multiple CPUs (20-30K TPS) however I cannot do this in production because of celery limitations (I cannot use a ProcessPoolExecutor inside a celery task)
- I cannot really tell when exactly does the crash happen (I'm not sure if this is relevant)

Comment: You don't say what OS your laptop is running, how much physical memory your laptop has, how much memory is free when the restart happens, if the restart always happens on the (say) 3009th item,  Have you checked any of these factors?

Comment: In general it is recommended to limit your pipeline to a few megabytes (2-3M). The `pipeline` feature is mainly there as a convenience instead of the `*multi()` methods, in that multiple operations can be combined within a pipeline, as opposed to a `multi` which only allows a singe operation of a given type.
I am curious as to why you are under the impression that it's slower if you decrease the batch size - the opposite should be true, since once a threshold is reached, all you are doing is simply pushing your local RAM

Comment: Perhaps you should also consider something like gevent or twisted as well.

Comment: @barny Please see the edited question.

Comment: 4G Physical RAM, or virtual RAM for Ubuntu? Or both? 12G swap for 4G RAM is stretching things to the limit although using an SSD may allow things to work for a while as memory needs grow above 4G - that degree of overcommit is probably going to stress things a lot as memory usage grows. I suspect you need a beefier virtual (and possibly physical) system to run this on.

Comment: Also understand that the `pipeline()` does not asynchronously submit operations to be processed. The operations themselves are performed in the `__exit__` method. Using Twisted or gevent would speed up things using a single thread/process only, however they might require some other modifications to your program.

Comment: @barny the specs are for the VM alone the host has 8GB ram. I don't think the issue is connected to RAM.

Comment: @MarkNunberg  Thanks for the tips. They indicate what could be the reason (to many requests in one call) but do not explain why does this happen. Also if there are such limitations they probably should be embedded in the client.

Comment: I don't think anything inherent in the python (e.g. programmed-in limitations) would make the OS crash - your app is stressing things too much. Note that VMWare isn't perfect, either - there is (or used to be, haven't checked recently) a problem running DB2 on Windows on Fusion with certain Haswell processors - the problem never occurred when run native.

Comment: @barny The OS does not crash, only the python interpreter does...

Comment: OK I'd read 'kernel' as OS kernel. However much the same principles apply.